# Defining a reference to an element to be stored in JSON format without using the element's class or id

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, dom, reference

I'd like to learn how I can  **define a reference** to the **target** element of any click event in a page to be stored in **JSON** (for transfer).

The solution shouldn't rely on using the class or id of the target.

Specifically, whenever an element (which **may not** have a `class` or `id`) is clicked in the page, I'm trying to define a reference to the targeted element that can be used stored in `JSON` format for transfer so that I can use the it in an identical page.

---

Example Usage:

This is a test where 2 or more users are working together in the same interface from different devices

- A collaboration app that serves 2 users identical pages:

User 1:

```
<body>
    <div class="body-wrapper">
        <button>Click Here</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button>Click Me</button>
        <div>
             <button>Or Click Me</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

User 2: (identical)

- when the button "Click Me" is the target of a click event, the listener returns some kind of reference to that button that I can send over the web (Here's where the JSON format becomes necessary)
- The outcome: I can echo the click on that button in User 2's DOM.

---

**Edit:**

As briefly discussed in the answer's comments, event delegation can be used to handle dynamically generated content. **Is this the proper combination of this question's answer with event delegation?**

```
$(document).on("mouseup mousedown click mousemove", function(e) {
    var element = e.target.index("body *");
    socket.emit("event", element, e);
});
```

Comment: I've updated the question to resolve a combination of Barmar's excellent answer with event delegation, as mentioned by CBroe in the answer comments below.

Comment: The `.on()` part is OK to target elements that might not have been part of the DOM at the time the event binding is executed. But you might get a problem here with event bubbling, since this might fire for more elements then you intend to. If you want to only handle the click on the original target element, but not on each of its ancestors as well, then you should prevent the event from bubbling up.

Comment: @CBroe I'm using this concept to develop an API for a web application environment that allows app developers to use this collaboration (such as event sharing between users working in the same interface). I can allow developers to use classes to decide what events to listen for. `$(document + ".collaborate")` for example might be the usage of this. So unintended event bubbling won't be an issue.

Comment: `$(document + ".collaborate")` won’t work though :-) – if you only want to listen to events for elements matching a certain selector, then you can pass that selector to `.on` as a second parameter, before the handler function: `$(document).on("click", ".collaborate", function(){})`. (That selector could be a lot more complex though if needed, doesn’t have to be a simple single class selector.)

Comment: @CBroe Ah, I see! Thanks. Yes, I'll incorporate the option of using classes to share specific events on specific elements as well as the group definition within an API defined function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the DOM is identical on both pages, you can use the element's index in the DOM:

```
$("button").click(function() {
    var position = $(this).index("body *");
    // Send "position" to the server
    ...
}
```

On the receiving page, you can find the corresponding button with:

```
$("body *").eq(position);
```

The proper way to do the event delegation you asked about is:

```
$(document).on("mouseup mousedown click mousemove", "button,checkbox,option", function(e) {
    var element = $(this).index("body *");
    socket.emit("event", element, e);
});
```

Change the list of element types to all the ones that you need to catch clicks on.

Comment: That's cool! I didn't even know elements had an index in the DOM.

Comment: This is probably the hardest question I've asked on SO out of hundreds of them, yet you answer it in 4 lines. +10

Comment: _“I didn't even know elements had an index in the DOM.”_ – They don’t (not in general) – this is using jQuery’s `index` method, which calculates the index within the selected elements itself.

Comment: @CBroe I see. Well, again, *JQuery to the rescue*

Comment: Make use of event delegation.

Comment: @CBroe Why? Nothing in the question suggests that he's creating the buttons dynamically. If that's necessary, it's entirely unrelated to his question.

Comment: I'm not generating them dynamically in my test scenario, but out of curiosity, can dynamically generated elements be handled this way as well?

Comment: @Barmar: I was referring to his (now removed) comment asking how to do event handling without having to bind events to multiple elements individually.

Comment: @CBroe Yes, I realized that was a silly comment, but your response DID bring up an important point about this question, see edit

Comment: I did not say it was “silly”, I just responded to it – if you want to react to events on multiple elements, without binding the event handler to every single one of them, then event delegation is a way to go: You react to the event once it has “bubbled up” to a parent element, and there you look which was the original _target_ of the event. As for handling events on dynamically created elements (that don’t exist at the time you bind the event), see jQuery’s documentation on `.on`

Comment: @CBroe yes, but it was asked without prior research. See that edit, it uses your mention of event delegation in combination with this answer.